# Какой инструмент выбрать для клиента и для работы с базой данных используя C#?

Tags: c#, ado.net

Какой инструмент выбрать для клиента и для работы с базой данных используя C#?

**ИСХОДНЫЕ ДАННЫЕ:**

1. преобладающий тип связи между таблицами 1:М;
2. будут использоваться различные запросы;
3. основной функционал клиента показан в форме "001_000_tst_Form1" приложенного файла;

Т.е. необходимо, чтобы можно было использовать:

- вкладки на форме;
- несколько таблиц на одной форме (панели);
- несколько полей таблиц вынесены на форму и их можно редактировать и  форматировать;
- возможность использования дополнительных кнопок (на форме не показаны);

**ОСНОВНОЕ ТРЕБОВАНИЕ:**

4. таблицы базы расположены на MySql;
5. клиент может быть разработан как в виде программы или в виде ВЕБ;

**ФОРМАЛЬНОЕ ТРЕБОВАНИЕ:**

6. Интуитивность разработки клиента (по принципу Access или LightSwitch);
7. оптимальное процесс обновление изменённых(отформатированных) данных в записи. 
   Т.е. данные автоматически обновляются в первоисточнике или обновляются по нажатию клавиши;
8. Возможность построения деревьев данных(меню) с возможностью поиска элементов (см. скрин);
9. возможность построения диаграмм различной аналитики на основании данных из таблиц;
10. возможность индикации полей таблицы (см. скрин);
11. возможность отображения фото в таблице;
    Т.е. имеется база сотрудников с фотографиями.
    Нужно чтобы отображались фото сотрудников в базе как в исходном положении таблицы, так и после фильтрации

Файл базы данных: http://transfiles.ru/7ug8a

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: в текущей постановке вопроса: клиенту excel (аналитику он умеет, даже с кубами работает), разработчику mysql workbench, и ни какого C#. Если хочется все самому писать, то WinForms (оригинальные) не стоит использовать точно, больно много руками делать придется, но в варианте от DevExpress или SyncFusion можно даже их. В текущей постановке вопроса не хватает огромного количества информации, необходимой, даже для примерной оценки, что конкретно использовать или не использовать. На ваш вопрос нет однозначного ответа, а опросники тут офтопик.

Comment: @rdorn 1. `клиенту excel` - я об этом думал, но как в Ексель организовать обратную связь? Т.е. чтобы клиент мог читать, редактировать, форматировать данные внутри ячейки, добавлять, удалять записи в таблицы, которые находятся на сервере. 2. `не хватает огромного количества информации` - не могли бы вы подсказать, что и где посмотреть, почитать про данный перечень вопросов.. может у вас более полный опросник

Comment: @rdorn  3.  `и ни какого C#` что имеете ввиду? Вообще не связываться с C#?

Comment: "ни какого C#" относилось к варианту с excel, и только. "Подробный опросник" называется Техническое задание, которое нужно вытрясти из клиента, и чем подробнее и точнее тем меньше придется переделывать. Обратную связь в excel можно организовать макросами на VBA например. Или дописать свой плагин, это сложнее, но может быть оправдано, опять же без четкого ТЗ что либо советовать сложно. Начните с получения четкого ТЗ от  клиента, тогда советы могут и не понадобиться.

Comment: я бы выбрал инструмент c# windows forms, только с диаграммами и фото внутри таблицы будут напряги наверно. я обычно решаю стандартными возможностями все проблемы, без сторонних компонентов (они как черный ящик). подумайте над интерфейсов врзможно фото внутри таблицы в ячейке отображать визуально не лучшее решение...

Answer (score 1):

Добрый день!

Всегда, когда речь идет о реляционных базах данных и языке C# - я советую использовать ORM [Entity Framework 6 (мануал)](https://professorweb.ru/my/entity-framework/6/level1/) и ссылка на NuGET [EF6](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework). Основное его преимущество - удобство создания объектной модели в Вашем коде буквально парой кликов, а также простота создания дальнейших запросов к БД с использованием созданной объектной модели и [LINQ to Objects](https://professorweb.ru/my/LINQ/base/level1/linq_index.php). `ADO.NET` это прошлый век, забудьте о нем.

Ваш необходимый функционал по отображению данных, цветовой индикации, дереву и прочим вещам полностью удовлетворяет технология [Windows Forms](https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/1.1.php) и ее стандартные контролы (`DataGridView`, `TreeView`, `TextBox`, `Chart`). Либо, если Вы знакомы с XAML, можете воспользоваться технологией [WPF](https://metanit.com/sharp/wpf/).